# php shopping cart, creating a sign up and pay online page

Tags: php, e-commerce

ok heres my problem, im creating a site where people sign up first then pay straight after, my problem is what if the customer who signs up uses a different card to pay so for example, his wife. im trying to work out how to match the sign up info and the payment info without having to store the card details and get an ssl cert.. i need this so i can tell if they paid.. im writing it in php, it currently sends me an email when they sign up rather than straight into a database, any help?

Comment: "any help?"....any code?

Comment: its a tough problem to troubleshoot in the abstract.  some code would go a long way

Answer (score 2):

Simplest thing that comes to mind would be to have options on the payment screen that let you:

(1) Use the billing info you supplied during registration
(2) Specify the name as it appears on the card (as most sites I've ordered from include)

Does this answer your question?

If you are concerned about matching the account to being paid if they use a different name, you most likely have some kind of $Session going on I would think.  Use the user's login information from the Session() and then you can tell.

Answer (score 2):

We use Authorize.Net for our payment processor.  They have two different APIs which give you different levels of control (AIM - Advanced, SIM - Simple).  From your description of not desiring a SSL Cert, SIM would be the best way to proceed.

We have designed our system to collect as much information as possible from the customer and then pass (via POST) to AuthNet's SIM method where they only need to enter in their card-specific information (number, expiration date, and CID).  If the transaction is successful (and also in some failure cases), they notify us by a pre-defined 'silent-post' transaction and also redirect the user to a 'relay url'.  We provide AuthNet with an order/invoice number as part of our original post data, so we can use it in their silent post to match up their payment with the appropriate order.

The SIM interface has worked well for us over the years and we now have it tweaked via CSS so that it closely resembles our site despite being hosted elsewhere, saving use far larger PCI-DSS compliance issues by doing everything locally.

Answer (score 0):

> im trying to work out how to match the sign up info and the payment info without having to store the card details and get an ssl cert

In that case the best advice is to use something like [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/), [Amazon Payments](https://payments.amazon.com), or [Google Checkout](http://checkout.google.com/). Other than that, your question was a bit hard to decipher.

> i need this so i can tell if they paid.. im writing it in php, it currently sends me an email when they sign up rather than straight into a database, any help?

Most 3rd party payment processors (PayPal, Google, Amazon), provide a way of checking payment status. Most also offer pinging a callback when the payment status changes.

- [PayPal IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn)
- [Amazon IPN](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSAggregatedGuide/index.html?APPNDX_IPN.html)
- [Google Notifications](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_PHP_NotificationAPIFunctions.html)

Answer (score -1):

Many credit-card processing options will send a response to your server containing crucial information about the user that you can use to verify that they have successfully paid. For example, PayPal has an IPN ([Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn)). You can use the data returned in this to automate a process on your server that states the user has paid.

My advice is to contact whoever is processing your credit-card transactions and ask what options they provide for relaying information back to your server to verify which users have suffessfully paid for the products/services.

Comment: I would much more prefer if when the user has paid it sends me their money, then I will update his website for him :)

Comment: @David: That's what IPN does. Once the processing-company has cleared payment, they confirm with you and you update their account data.

Comment: Sorry for the miss interpretation, I was trying to be witty. By saying that he should have he user pay then I get sent the money for no reason what so ever. Then I would provide the website updates for me :) Basically meaning I get free money! Yay!